# Como combinar imagenes con tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

Estoy intentando crear una Dataset de imagenes en el que cada una es la combinacion de dos imagenes (las cuales son concatenadas una tras la otra).

Estoy usando ImageDataGenerator para leer las imagenes del directorio y aprovechar el preprocesado que esto te da (reescalado, modo de la imagen y clasificacion segun la organizacion del directorio). Pero no parece simple, el combinar dos ImageDataGenerator en uno.

Existe alguna forma de hacer esto. Seguramente Tf tenga algun mecanismo para leer las imagenes de los dos directorios y combinarlos para crear un unico Dataset.

Comment: Hi there, this is [es.so]. Please translate your question to spanish, otherwise it will be closed. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada.

Answer (score 0):

si las imágenes tiene el mismo tamaño puedes usar:

```
tf.concat()
```